# Is there a way to stop levitation 254 from shooting you into the air when landing?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

To mimic low gravity, I used the command `/effect @p minecraft:levitation 1000000 254`. You can change the effect boldness to make you jump higher or glide to the ground faster. My problem with this is that it makes you jump very high into the sky when you glide to the ground from a high surface. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: With 254 it isn't really 0G, that would by 255. But with 255, you would never land on the ground to be able to jump again, so do you actually want to simulate 0G or do you want players to slowly glide down? Also I have not encountered higher jumping with this yet. Are you sure you don't have jump boost left from earlier experiments? If you have lag, sometimes effects are applied, but not shown or the other way around. Try `effect @p jump_boost 0`.

Comment: if you have 254 levitation and glide all the way to the ground from a high surface in gms or gma it will shoot you into the sky. I know that I do not have jump_boost though. And i want to simulate a gliding effect that doesnt make you get shot into the air

Comment: I deliberated with some other bug experts and it's likely a desynchronization between the client and the server that's causing this. If you give yourself an effect of level 254, the client interprets it as -2, but the server interprets it as 254, which for some reason acts the same as 1. When you land, the client asks the server for the correct location and momentum and he gets updated to the higher position. And for some reason you get fall damage. The problem with all of this: No matter how many bugs there are in this, they won't ever get fixed, because effect levels above 4 aren't supported

Comment: So you would have to somehow block the player from going up at all after landing. It should be possible to detect if the player is high in the air and lands and to then put a barrier block above his head so that he doesn't get launched up or at least only a small bit. Maybe it could even be a NoAI shulker, an invisible boat or something else that can be at variable heights and can block movement. But all of this can have all sorts of bugs itself and I already played around with levitation for about 90 minutes today and have to go to bed. So I'll try to do it tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update in 19w37a (for 1.15): Levitation 254 simply works now, I was not able to reproduce the bouncing behaviour. So the solution below is only useful for older versions. I'll keep it in the 1.12 syntax unless someone requests me to update it.

---

I have no real solution to stop the bouncing (and I don't think there is one), but it can be detected when a player is first off the ground and then on the ground again. And it's possible to give the player a lot of downwards momentum to force him back to the ground, again with negative levitation. I don't exactly know why this works and doesn't produce an endless loop of bounces, but it works and that's all that matters. Of course it looks very ridiculous when a player elegantly glides to the ground and then suddenly does a very high and very quick jump and is then pushed back on the ground. But this is just a workaround. I think a true fix won't come for a long time if you don't write your own mod, because it's a bug in an unsupported feature (effect level above 4).

Setup:

```
/scoreboard objectives add antiJump dummy
```

Loop:

```
execute @a[score_antiJump_min=0,score_antiJump=0] ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~-.1 ~ air 0 scoreboard players set @s antiJump 1
scoreboard players add @a[score_antiJump_min=1] antiJump 1
execute @a ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~-.1 ~ air 0 scoreboard players set @s antiJump 1
effect @a[score_antiJump_min=2,score_antiJump=2] levitation 0
effect @a[score_antiJump_min=2,score_antiJump=2] levitation 1 128
scoreboard players set @a[score_antiJump_min=9] antiJump 0
effect @a[score_antiJump=0] levitation 1000000 254
```

This gives every player on the ground by default the state of 0. When they are in the air (there's an air block 0.1 blocks below them), they get state 1. When they are then on the ground again, they get a high negative levitation effect (128) that pushes them down against the bouncing so that they still fly about 5 blocks up, but they are back on the ground after only 0.4 seconds. Also their state starts ticking up. When it reaches 9, it's reset to 0 and they get the levitation effect 254 again.

This system only checks for air below the player, no other small blocks (like slab, carpet, chests, etc.), but I tested it and it actually works just as well with them. The only exception is if you build really big towers out of blocks without a hitbox (signs, banners, buttons, ...) and the player falls right through it. Then he can actually still bounce up the regular height. To solve that, you can just duplicate all the `execute detect` commands (keeping the order) with `standing_sign` or similar instead of air or you can set the `9` in the second last command to a higher number, but that could, if it's too high, prevent players from jumping for a while after they were bounced.

This system is almost unnoticable when walking/jumping around normally. There are some movements with stairs or water that behave differently than you would expect, but they should be pretty rare. I first made a system where a block would be set on top of the player to keep him from going up, but that was very unelegant in comparison to this one and had much potential for unwanted side effects. This system shouldn't have that. It's not perfect, but it's (to my knowledge) the best that can be done with commands.

Comment: If you want more explanation or a 1.13-ready version, just ask.

Comment: What kinds of side effects. You could use the invisible barrier block for example.

Comment: Yes, but I can only set it two or three blocks above your head. If I set it two blocks high, you hit the barrier block itself (with your head apparently, it's very weird) and bounce, and if I set it three blocks high, you can sometimes be too high and bounce again when you land again (even though that should be impossible in theory). A slab works, but it's visible and players could destroy slabs above their head by jumping under it.

Comment: You can still see my old solution in the previous version of this answer, but I think this one is better. And the other one also has the mistake that you had to give everyone a score in the scoreboard first, this new solution gives it automatically when you're first in the air.